# nginx error log log_format variables

Tags: nginx

I want to specify log format for nginx error logs, but I could not find any variable for errors.
I found required variables for access logs like below:

```
log_format test'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
```

Is there any $error, $error_body or something like this that could be matched for errors?

Comment: What do you mean by «errors»?

Answer (score 4):

No, `$status` is the one you want. It contains both erroneous and successful statuses. You should `grep` the `access_log` for statuses indicating the errors and the `error_log` for their causes. I guess you're misunderstanding the concept of access and error log separation.

Comment: No i know the differences but I'm trying to specify a format for it  .